# Sending JSON Objects in DataTables aaData instead of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jquery DataTables plugin on my application and I am really happy so far with the functionality although I would like to pass the data slightly differently to the aaData attribute.

currently it only seems to accept the javascript array as

```
 [
    ['value','value','value'],
    ...,
    ...,
]
```

I would like to be able to use an object rather than arrays because it will be cleaner and help me extend some filtering I am doing easier. how can I pass it a javascript variable that looks like this ( not loading via AJAX ).

```
[
   {'id':1,'status':0,'name': 'hello world'},
   ...,
   ...,
]
```

Example trying to use sAjaxSource with local variable
http://live.datatables.net/utecax/edit#

Example trying to use array of objects with aaData
http://live.datatables.net/iyavud/5/edit

Comment: something like this? http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: yea the problem I have with that is I am not loading via an external source. data is just a javascript variable and then  "sAjaxSource" complains

Comment: have you tried using `aaData` instead of `sAjaxSource`?.. then define your columns as in the example?

Comment: yea I can only get aaData to take an array of arrays which is somewhat clumsy I think when it comes to referencing it especially when I am using a plugin for filtering and setting the expected column which differs between tables. will udpate with live examples in a sec.

Comment: works fine here using aaData.  You just had the wrong properties set in your columns http://live.datatables.net/iyavud/6/edit

Comment: thanks want to answer it below and ill give you the answer

Comment: Just did :)  Hope you understand why yours wasn't working.  You just had to use mData to set the property so datatables knows which values should go in which column

Comment: yea thanks I had tried that before but using sTitle as well and I think I had also missed a property or something. but yea have it working fine now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can pass in the array of objects via aaData property, then use aoColumns property to define which column should recieve which data

```
  $('#example').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": data,// <-- your array of objects
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "render_engine" }, // <-- which values to use inside object
            { "mData": "browser" },
            { "mData": "platform" },
            { "mData": "enging_version" },
            { "mData": "css_grade" }
        ]
  });
```

Comment: Solution worked fine, but the link provided is not related to the problem.

Comment: In new version of datatables.net 1.10.12, the `aaData` becomes `data` and `aoColumns` becomes `columns`; Updated solution can be found in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hifni/9pj1jv3d/1/)