# Error when converting JSON objects into jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, datatable

I've been trying to convert a JSON object into datatables rows. I think the syntax which I'm using is correct, but I doubt there is a problem with my JSON data

First, I'm getting a XML in String format from server. Next I'm coverting this xml string to JSON object using

```
var xmlData = JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json(data));    //x2js library
console.log(xmlData);
```

I'm getting this output in the console.log (NOTE: Firefox console: Look at the " which is present at start and end even though I just displayed only xmlData using console.log) . If I display it in chrome console there is no " at the start and end, maybe this how firefox and chrome handles the console output

```
"{"Loans":{"loan":[{"id":"2","loanAmount":"200000","loanDuration":"10","status":"Pending"}]}}"
```

This is the code I'm using for datatable conversion

```
$('#loan-data').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "aaData": xmlData,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": "Loans.loan.loanAmount" },
        { "mData": "Loans.loan.loanDuration" }
    ]
});
```

My table in html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="loan-data">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Loan Amount</th>
            <th>Loan Repayment (Months)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting the following error

```
DataTables warning: table id=loan-data - Requested unknown parameter 'Loans.loan.loanAmount' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

I've worked in datatables before like simple forEach iteration display. But this object to datatable is new to me. Any Ideas what I've done wrong.

The above codes are based on the answer from this SO question

[Sending JSON Objects in DataTables aaData instead of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160483/sending-json-objects-in-datatables-aadata-instead-of-arrays)

Comment: Try this: `var xmlData = x2js.xml_str2json(data)`, you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` as it creates a string from object.

Comment: @dfsq ,I tried that, it doesn't shows any alert, it simply shows as no data available in data, but in firefox console i get a syntax error at the top of html page