# Sending JSON Objects in DataTables from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am trying to populate datatable from JSON object but getting the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=filteredAlertsTable - Requested unknown parameter 'messageId' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Here is my code:

```
var dataSet = '${data}';
$('#filteredAlertsTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": dataSet,
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "mData": "messageId" },
                      { "mData": "host" },
                      { "mData": "creationTime" },
                      { "mData": "resolvedTime" },
                      { "mData": "severity" },
                      { "mData": "alertText" }
        ]
    } );
```

I am  getting **dataSet** from javascript variable, I tried passing the following,

```
[{
    "severity": "Severity",
    "creationTime": "CreationTime",
    "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime",
    "appName": "AppName",
    "host": "Host",
    "messageId": "MessageId",
    "alertText": "AlertText"
},
{
    "severity": "Severity1",
    "creationTime": "CreationTime1",
    "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime1",
    "appName": "AppName1",
    "host": "Host1",
    "messageId": "MessageId1",
    "alertText": "AlertText1"
}]
```

**and**

```
{
    "mData": [{
        "severity": "Severity",
        "creationTime": "CreationTime",
        "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime",
        "appName": "AppName",
        "host": "Host",
        "messageId": "MessageId",
        "alertText": "AlertText"
    },
    {
        "severity": "Severity1",
        "creationTime": "CreationTime1",
        "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime1",
        "appName": "AppName1",
        "host": "Host1",
        "messageId": "MessageId1",
        "alertText": "AlertText1"
    }]
}
```

I have gone thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160483/sending-json-objects-in-datatables-aadata-instead-of-arrays) question but I still can't figure out what's wrong

Here is my HTML code.

```
<table id="filteredAlertsTable"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Message Id</th>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Creation Time</th>
            <th>Resolved Time</th>
            <th>Severity</th>
            <th>Alert Text</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I suggest pass the same `format` back as json which matches your initialization in `dataTables`. For ex: if `messageId` is the first `mData` during initialization append it as first element of array in `json` object which is passed back!!

Comment: From my experience with **DataTables** and that sort of error, you should double-check your HTML and be sure you have as many rows as you have table headers. This might be the issue, can't tell for sure until I see the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `dataSet` is a string. Most likely caused by `'${data}'` so it for the dataTable looks like this :

```js
var dataSet = '[{ "severity": "Severity", "creationTime": "CreationTime", "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime", "appName": "AppName", "host": "Host", "messageId": "MessageId",    "alertText": "AlertText"},{    "severity": "Severity1",    "creationTime": "CreationTime1", "resolvedTime": "ResolvedTime1", "appName": "AppName1", "host": "Host1", "messageId": "MessageId1", "alertText": "AlertText1"}]';
```

As JSON it works right away -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q78tu48q/**

So make sure your string actually *is* in JSON format :

```js
$('#filteredAlertsTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaData": JSON.parse(dataSet),
        "aoColumns": [
                      { "mData": "messageId" },
                      { "mData": "host" },
                      { "mData": "creationTime" },
                      { "mData": "resolvedTime" },
                      { "mData": "severity" },
                      { "mData": "alertText" }
        ]
    } );
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/u76bLpa3/**